# Maybe monad: how to avoid storing T-typed value in Maybe<T> instance?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, monads

In the following coliru you will find my implementation of the "Maybe" monad.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82978c254410ba6e

The problem that I have with it is that "Nothing" values carry with them an unnecessary `T`-typed data member just like "Just" values which do need it.

Is it possible to implement `Maybe<T>` without "Nothing" values being as big as "Just" values, *and without resorting to dynamic allocation* of the `T`-typed values?

I have tried defining `Just<T>` and `Nothing<T>` as derived classes of `Maybe<T>` with `Just<T>` being the only class having a `T`-typed data member. The problem with this is that then `Monad<T>::bind` is better implemented as a virtual member function, or at least that's what feels most natural to me, and it can't be because it's also a function template.

As an aside, I'd like to know if there's a simpler syntax than

```
template <typename Fun>
auto bind(Fun&& f) -> decltype(f(T{})) {
    typedef typename decltype(f(T{}))::value_type R;
    /*
     * blabla
     */
}
```

to achieve the same effect and get a hold of `R`.

Comment: `boost::optional` is the usual c++ Maybe monad implementation. Here's an article on how it is implemented: http://efesx.com/2009/12/04/boost-optional-and-its-internals/

Comment: @lisyarus Interesting read, but apparently `boost::optional` solves the problem of the overhead of _constructing_ the `T`-typed data member. It doesn't remove the need for `sizeof(T)` bytes (and some more) being occupied by `optional<T>` instances even when they contain nothing. Shall I conclude, since even boost doesn't save the memory, that ot's impossible?

Comment: How do you pass and return instances of this monad?  prvalues aren't polymorphic.  Pass-by-reference works ok for input parameters, but not for return values, out parameters, or in/out parameters.

Comment: @BenVoigt As much as I hate to say it, I'm merely a beginner at C++, and at the moment prvalues still lie far ahead in my journey of enlightenment. It just looks to me like my coliru example code works, and so do the `Just<T>` and `Nothing<T>` factory functions, so I really don't know how to answer you here.

Comment: @jrsala: Sure, but your example code doesn't have derived classes.  When you start using derived classes, your return values will face the *slicing* problem.  Factory functions returning by pointer (or reference) to base class always have to use dynamic allocation, because the required size isn't known a-priori, so the caller can't reserve a buffer for the return value to be left in.

Comment: @jrsala I think there is no alternative. Either you know the size beforehead (and live with `sizeof(T)` overhead), or you fallback to dynamic allocation. The latter can be done in various ways: you can make Maybe<T> polymorphic, or you can allocate the `T` itself.

Comment: @BenVoigt I hadn't even thought about that. I guess I should give up trying, then. I suppose the `boost::optional` optimization is the best one can hope for. If you want to make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @lisyarus OK, point taken. Thanks! Whoever makes an answer first gets dem juicy rep points

Comment: By the way, there is a pitfall in doing `decltype(f(T{}))` - the type `T` can lack the default constructor. The correct way is to do `decltype(f(std::declval<T>()))`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, thank you! By the way, very nice hat :)

Comment: @lisyarus Thanks! One more arcane incantation to add to my notebook

Comment: tl;dr all values of type `Maybe<T>` are of size `sizeof(Maybe<T>)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, the compiler needs to know the size of an object it is working with, and objects of equal types have equal sizes. When this happens to be a problem, pointers and polymorphism come.

This means that in your case either you know the size beforehead (and live with `sizeof(T)` overhead), or you fallback to dynamic allocation. The latter can be done in various ways: you can make `Maybe<T>` polymorphic, or you can allocate the `T` itself.

I cannot ignore some problems with your code; both are related to one irritating fact: the type `T` can lack a default constructor. You can ignore this, or you have to make some fixes.

Firstly, you cannot do `decltype(f(T{}))`, even if `T{}` is only for type inference and the constructor in fact is not called. There is a standard way to do exactly this: `std::declval<T>()` returns an object of type `T` (and, in fact, is not implemented at all, only declared; this is enough for type inference). So, you should do `decltype(f(std::declval<T>()))`.

Secondly, you cannot simply declare `T _value`, since you have no constructor to call when constructing a `Nothing<T>`. This can simply be solved by dynamic allocation, but there is another way (used in `boost::optional`): store an array of `char` of size `sizeof(T)`, leave it uninitialized, and use *placement new* when actually creating an object of type `T`. This approach is described [here](http://efesx.com/2009/12/04/boost-optional-and-its-internals/).

Finally, answering your last question: no, there is no simpler way to do this:

```
typedef typename decltype(f(T{}))::value_type R;
```

which, according to my previous words, should look like

```
typedef typename decltype(f(std::declval<T>()))::value_type R;
```

Comment: I think when you wrote `std::decltype<T>()` you meant `std::declval<T>()`? And thanks for the help!